# Transformations and coordinate Systems

Tags: calculus, intuition, transformation

I am working on some practice exercises (not homework) on transformations and need some intuition and help.

One of the questions is: $(u,v)=f(x,y)$
where $ \quad u= { e }^{ x }\cos(y), \quad v = { e }^{ x }\sin(y).\quad \quad $

A)  It asks to compute the Jacobian $\operatorname{det} Df$ which is ${ e }^{ 2x }$, next it asks to find the formulas for the local inverses of $f$ when they exist. How do I find inverses when there are two variables involved?

B)  It also asks to sketch of the lines $x=\text{constant}$ and $y = \text{constant}$ and I believe if I let $x$ to be some constant $c$ then I get $(u,v)$ to be $(c\cos(y),c\sin(y))$  but how do I graph this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Part A, you need to find $(x,y)=(x(u,v), y(u,v))$. You might start by writing $u^{2}+v^{2}$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. That should make it easy for you to find $x(u,v)$.

For Part B, you have correctly derived the expression describing the transformation of lines of constant $x$. Think about polar coordinates, and you should see what shape that expression describes in the $(u,v)$-plane. Lines of constant $y$ transform to similarly simple curves in the $(u,v)$-plane.

EDIT TO ADD:

Okay, so you've pretty much gotten through it, I think, with the help of some comments, but here's the remainder of Part A for completeness:

$$u^{2}+v^{2} = e^{2x}\cos^{2}y + e^{2x}\sin^{2}y = e^{2x},$$

and, therefore, 
$$x = {1\over2}\log(u^2+v^2).$$

And you correctly derived that 
$$y=\tan^{-1}{v\over u}.$$

Now note that this is, indeed, only a *local* inversion, because the arctangent is not uniquely defined (you have to specify the particular range of values, for example, $-\pi/2\lt y \lt\pi/2$).

Do you now have a better idea of the curves on the $(u,v)$-plane described by lines of constant $x$ and $y$?

Comment: so if I had $u=x-y$ and $v=x+2y$ how do I invert that for $x$ and $y$. I guess I am looking for more examples with respect to inverses when multiple variables are involved.

Comment: @KjTada If you had $u=x−y$ and $v=x+2y$ you would need to solve for $x$ and $y$ the linear system of two equations: $$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
u=x-y \\ 
v=x+2y
\end{array}
\right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=\frac{2}{3}u+\frac{1}{3}v \\ 
y=\frac{1}{3}v-\frac{1}{3}u
\end{array}
\right. $$

Comment: thanks, but when I plug the value of y and x into $v=x+2y$ I dont get v back instead I get $v=2u+v$. Also do you find the inverse mostly with trial and error when multiple variables are involved or is there a more systematic approach to this.

Comment: No, you get back $v$: $$v=x+2y=\frac{2}{3}u+\frac{1}{3}v+\frac{2}{3}v-\frac{2}{3}u=v.$$ The main difference with the exercise is that  you have a *non linear* system of two equations.

Comment: Thanks for help with this. For the original exercise (non linear)  I get $y=tan^{-1} (v/u)$ is that correct and for x I get $x=ln(tan(v/e^{x}))$

Comment: @KjTada Well, $v/u=\tan y$. The rest of this conversation cannot continue here because this is 
Rick Goldstein's answer. If I have time I will post an answer tomorrow. ADDED $x=\frac{1}{2}\log \left( u^{2}+v^{2}\right) $.